# Javascript height and media query at the same time

Tags: javascript, css, height, media-queries

I am assuming this is possible but I may be wrong.

I am practising making mobile websites and I would like a combination of the following 2 features -
Javascript to shrink menu bar when scrolling down.
Media query to show larger menu bar when orientation is landscape.

I have the code for both -
Javascript -

```
<script>
             $(document).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop()>1){
            // animate fixed div to small size:
            $('.container').stop().animate({ height: 40 },100);
            $('.menuicon').stop().animate({ height: 40, width: 40 },100);
        } else {
            //  animate fixed div to original size
            $('.container').stop().animate({ height: 100},100);
            $('.menuicon').stop().animate({ height: 100, width: 100},100);
        }
    }); 

    </script>
```

Media Query -

```
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {  
    .container{
    height:16%;
    }
    .menuicon{
    width:16%;
    }

    #menu{
    padding-top:16%;
            }
}
```

The media query worked fine before javascript, however since the before and after height is defined, it does not change depending on orientation anymore.

Is there a way to include a media query like this in my javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: You could override the inline height set by js with `!important` in the css

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Honestly I didnt even know about !important until now. From the quick read I have had it seems to put if after the 16% but it didn't seem to change anything. I'm guessing I have done this wrong.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it seems to put if after the 16%"

Comment: Sorry, should have explained better. So going off the example its as if it should be placed - {padding-top:16% !important;} and so on.

Comment: Yes that's the correct syntax

Comment: Am I placing it correctly? It hasn't changed anything?

Comment: Could be the animate still animates it, can you put this in a http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=llBo1HrV14      The width of the red div extends as planned but the height does not.

Comment: instead of css do it through javascript. On resize event check for the window.innerwidth and window.innerHeight. If window.innerwidth > window.innerHeight, its landscape mode and change the icon size else portrait mode change it to default. If you are using javascript then it will trigger the resize event on orientation change

Comment: Hu Mukesh, thanks for commenting. I am afraid I am a total beginner with JS, so I'd just like to double check that I have the concept right before going to read up on it. Would it be best if I set it up so that - if screen is landscape, execute larger banner which scales down to half size when scrolling, if not landscape, execute smaller banner...if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to go down a different route with this one.

I created 2 sets of menu classes, one for Portrait and one for Landscape. I used display:none to hide whichever is not needed and used the following CSS to dictate which to show -

```
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {  
    .containerL{

        display:block;
    }
            .menuiconL{

                display:block;
    }



            #menu{
                padding-top:105px;
            }
} 

        @media all and (orientation:portrait) {
        .containerP{

        display:block;
    }
            .menuiconP{

                display:block;
    }
        }
```